# What is the specific heat of plasticine?

Tags: thermodynamics, collision

**Does anyone know what is the specific heat of plasticine?**

I tried a lot to find it in google, but I couldn't.

I need it for making a problem in physics (inelastic collisions).

I could use clay instead of plasticine (the specific heat of clay is $878\frac{J}{Kg\cdot K}$), but:

- some of my students are more familiar with plasticine, so I want this material and
- I don't' know if specific heat of clay is $878\frac{J}{Kg\cdot K}$ when it is dry (so does not occur inelastic collision).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You seem to be a teacher, so why not jus measure th specialfic heat of the plastilin  you use.

Comment: @trula I don't think it's that easy though since you need a setup to prevent the energy added to the system from escaping to the surroundings. That's a major pain.

Comment: @trula also I don't have access to a lab.

Comment: You do not need a lab. just water at low temperature , the plastilin  in high temperature water than transferring it to the low temp, so the only thinks you need ist a thermometer , and two measured amounts of water.

Comment: @trula , thanks I 'll try it!